# How to save my own unique identifier when I add a contact to android programatically

Tags: android, android-contacts

When saving a contact to the Android contacts database, I would like to save my own unique identifier to the contact. How can this be achieved?

Here is my attempt so far,

```
    private void saveMyId(int myId, ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops){
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
                        newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue("MyId", myId).build()
        );
    }
```

This crashes with the following error

> android.content.OperationApplicationException: insert failed at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithOperationApplicationExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't do that.
Contacts are stored within internal database which has only its defined columns. You can't add your own columns. You can find the list of columns in the documentation of [ContactsContract.Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html).

If you want extra columns for your app, you need to store them in your own database. This will require that you somehow merge the system contacts data and your own data when querying the db. In this case I'd probably utilize [CursorWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html). You will need to save your data to the system db and your own db. Generally, it will be rather a non-trivial code.